# union of finite bounded set and uniformly bounded set is bounded

Tags: general-topology, arzela-ascoli

Let $A, G \subset C ([a, b])$, $G = \{g_1, g_2, ..., g_m\}$ (finite set). 
Prove that if: i) $A || .. ||$ $\infty$-bounded then $A \cup G$ too.
ii) $A$ equicontinuous in $x_o$ then $A \cup G$ also.

for i) since $G$ is finite it has a max and a min element. I tried the triangle inequality taking the distance of any two element of $A$ and $G$.

ii) Don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Show from the definitions:

A union of two $\infty$-bounded sets is $\infty$-bounded.

A finite set is $\infty$-bounded.

Show the same two facts for equicontinuous sets.

For the finite case use that a single continuous function on $[a,b]$ is bounded and uniformly continuous.